# R: dynamic variable name comparisons

Tags: r, dplyr

I recoded a bunch of variables in a dataset, and and gave the newly recoded variables the prefix "r_" in my dataset.

I'd like to run `table` on the pairs to ensure the recoding was correct. Something like `table(v1, r_v1)`, but I need to do it for lots of variables. They are not in any particular order, so I couldn't use indexing.

Here is a reproducible example of data one can use (also any tips on optimizing that code are appreciated!).

```
mtcars %>% select(c(disp,hp)) %>%
mutate_all(funs(if_else(.>100,1,0))) %>%
rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), paste0('r_', names(.)))) %>%
cbind(mtcars,.)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When I run your code, I end up with columns named `"r_disp_r"` and `"r_hp_r"`, but you only talk about an `r` prefix. Which is correct?

Comment: Well when I run the second line to `mutate` the two variables, I wanted to give them a marker so I knew what they were. The last two variables in the dataset are the final ones.

Comment: Updated code to provide cleaner version of example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use variable names and simple for loop. Calling your modified data `dd`,

```
orig = c("disp", "hp")
trans = paste0("r_", orig)

check_list = list()
for (i in seq_along(orig)) {
  check_list[[i]] = table(dd[[orig[i]]], dd[[trans[i]]])
  # or whatever other check you want to do
}

check_list
```

You can then examine the `check_list` contents one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things in the tidy format with which you started:
    library(purrr)
    library(tidyr)

```
mtcars %>% 
select(disp,hp) %>% 
mutate_all(funs(r = if_else(.>100,1,0))) %>% 
mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
gather(key = key, value = value, -index) %>% 
separate(key, c("Variable", "Type")) %>% 
mutate(Type = ifelse(is.na(Type), "Original", "Recode")) %>% 
spread(key = Type, value = value) %>% 
select(-index) %>%  
split(.$Variable) %>% 
map(~ select(.,-Variable)) %>% 
map(~ table(.))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with some of the commands here like `index` or `gather`, can you walk me through what each line is doing?

Comment: You need a unique identifier for each row in order to apply the spread function.  This keeps all the data together.  I just created a column with the row numbers, but you could make up any arbitrary index.

Gather converts the row from wide to long format.  That is, all the columns are transformed into a key-value structure.  Since the `index` needs to remain for the `spread()` function, keep it separate from the key-value columns.

Run the pipeline through the `spread()` line to see what results: one row per variable per observation, with original and recoded side by side.